# How to configure linux docker containers to connect via ldap to ad for user authentication

Tags: docker, ldap, grafana

Working on the latest graphite/grafana docker container which is a linux base and would like to have it use ldap to reach out to AD for user auth.

I was able to SSH to the container and install openldap then make a successfully query to AD.

I was able to configure the port forwarding for ldap from the instance to the container. However authentication is failing with a protocol error back to the container.

Does anyone have any concrete steps for setting this up please? Appreciated.